# Comando git log para todos commits de um especifico arquivo

Tags: git

É possível verificar o git log para todos os commits de um especifico arquivo.

Eu fiz um commit para um arquivo foo.txt e agora não mostra mais no histórico git.

meu comando:

```
git log foo.txt
```

Eu quero procurar o todos os registros de commits para este arquivo, e então encontrar meu commit "perdido".

Comment: O comando para listar os *commits* de um arquivo é justamente esse da sua pergunta. Será que você não está em um *branch* diferente de onde foi feito o *commit*? Ou num *commit* anterior a esse que você está procurando?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git log --follow arquivo
```

Em todas as branches

```
git log --follow --all arquivo
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar o seguinte comando

```
git log -p myFile
```