# Como encontrar um determinado arquivo em todos os branches?

Tags: git

**Primeira busca:** Preciso encontrar um branch ou commit que possui um arquivo que foi perdido... porém eu tenho vários branches e vários commits em cada um desses branches...

O arquivo criado se chamaria: `projecs/web-sistema/js/add-script-android-platform.js`, existe algum comando ou maneira de rastrear esse arquivo dentro de toda a estrutura do GIT, sem ter que abrir cada branch e ficar procurando cada commit no https://dev.azure.com/?

> detalhes: os branches estão mais ou menos assim: `feature/sprint_1/create-platform, feature/sprint_2/modify-platform ...`

**Segunda busca:** Talvez este arquivo não esteja no projeto, ele pode ter sido criado pelo mapeamento do gulp, o que eu teria que encontrar então seria todos os logs do gulpfile.js que tenha esse mapeamento internamente.

Eu sei que se eu fizer isso, eu terei todos os logs do arquivo:
`git log gulfile.js`

Mas teria que filtrá-lo apenas onde a continuação do path possa ter esta nomenclatura:

`'add-script-android-platform.js'`

Eu tentei [estes comandos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/268174/comando-git-log-para-todos-commits-de-um-especifico-arquivo) mas nenhum funcionou.

Comment: Você lembra o nome e caminho do arquivo?

Comment: Esse: projecs/web-sistema/js/add-script-android-platform.js, só não sei o branch, nem o commit., o arquivo está mapeado no header da HTML, mas não ta no projeto. Provavelmente, não foi feito o merge deste branch com o master. Eu preciso localizá-lo.

Comment: E você não lembra nenhum branch que possa ter deletado esse arquivo?

Comment: Estou desconfiado que ele tenha outro nome mapeado no gulp, e tenha sido gerado com esse nome, e provavelmente, tenha que procurar esse mapeamento dentro do gulpfile.js que está modificado em um branch que eu não sei qual é.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como solucionei o problema, usei o seguinte comando:

`git log gulpfile.js`

Depois fui lendo as mensagens do commit, e fazendo checkout nos commits:

Exemplo: `git checkout 374124d1`

E vendo se aparecia os arquivos na raiz do projeto, na pasta "js", até que apareceu  ele na lista. Encontrei no terceiro checkout.
Então entrei no Azure e procurei a ID:

Encontrei o commit: `374124d106ce81f8da0bb625b77273d7148cd770`

Answer (score 2):

O que você precisa fazer, primeiro, é encontrar qual commit deletou esse arquivo, para isso, basta utilizar o seguinte comando:

```
git log --all --diff-filter=D -- <seu_arquivo>
```

Isso vai te dar todos os commits que deletaram esse arquivo. Para descobrir qual branch contém aquele commit, basta utilizar:

```
git branch -a --contains <hash_do_commit>
```

Daí, para restaurar o arquivo, basta fazer um `git checkout` para o commit.

Comment: Eu usei o comando, não encontrou nada, estou desconfiado que esteja mapeado no gulp mesmo. Mas eu gostei do comando...

Comment: @IvanFerrer então ou o arquivo não era versionado pelo git (no caso de estar no .gitignore) ou ele não foi deletado em nenhum branch...

Comment: Descobri o commit, agora queria pegar o branch desse commit.